# FTP get file modified date with Synapse

Tags: delphi, ftp, lazarus, freepascal

I'm making an auto updater using Synapse, it should download files that are newer than local ones based on their modification date.
But from ftp I'm getting creation time instead of modification, tried with custom command like this:

```
var
  ftp:tftpsend;
...
ftp.List('',false);
for i:=0 to ftp.ftplist.Count-1 do begin
  item:=ftp.FtpList[i];
  ftp.FTPCommand('MDTM '+ item.FileName);
  //decode date
  if (ftp.ResultCode=213) then begin
    s:=ftp.ResultString;
    s:=copy(s,5,length(s));
    date:=encodeDateTime(
    strtoint(copy(s,1,4)),
    strtoint(copy(s,5,2)),
    strtoint(copy(s,7,2)),
    strtoint(copy(s,9,2)),
    strtoint(copy(s,11,2)),
    strtoint(copy(s,13,2)),
    0);
    item.FileTime:=date;
  end;
```

FileZilla is able to show it correctly. What's going on?

Comment: So show us verbose FileZilla log file, as well as a transcript of your Pascal FTP session.

Comment: "*But from ftp I'm getting creation time instead of modification*" - then the FTP server is broken, because `MDTM` is [specifically designed](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3659#section-3) to get a file's modification time only. That being said, the `MDTM` spec also says: "*However, where supported, the "modify" fact that can be provided in the result from the new MLST command is recommended as a superior alternative.*" Did you try that yet?

Comment: Turned out that ftp command is ok, difference is probably in the server timezone which FileZilla manages to compensate for. File uploaded just now via Filezilla is 2 hours older when I next download it with my code..